# Animación en CSS: pelota que rebote y se deforme en el suelo y no en el aire

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer una animación usando HTML y CSS, más específicamente quiero hacer que un balón de fútbol se encuentre rebotando en la página web y que éste, al hacer contacto con el suelo, se contraiga y luego cuando deje el suelo que vuelva a su forma original.

```css
#pelota {
  position: absolute;
  animation: rebota 1s alternate infinite ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rebota {
  0% {
    top: 600px;
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png" width="100" height="100" id="pelota">
```

Por el momento con mi código logro que se vea la animación de contracción de la pelota pero **se visualiza su deformación en el aire y no cuando toca el suelo**, y lo que deseo es que se deforme al tocar el suelo exactamente, su ayuda seria de mucha utilidad para mí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo hace falta trabajar un poco el estilo, aquí tienes tu pelota, te ha quedado muy bien, saludos.

```css
#pelota {
  position: absolute;
  animation: rebota 1s alternate infinite ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rebota {
  0% {
    top: 600px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  10% {
    top: 560px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png" width="100" height="100" id="pelota">
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como lo tienes ahora la pelota va a ir caer de 200px a los 600px, pero si la pantalla tiene una altura mayor o menor que esos 670px (los 600px de la posición más los 70 del alto) entonces la pelota se va a ver rebotando en el aire (para resoluciones mayores) o "bajo el suelo" (para resoluciones menores).

Si lo que quieres es que siempre rebote contra el suelo (la parte baja de la pantalla), una solución sencilla sería usar `bottom` en lugar de `top`. De ese modo la animación ocurrirá de abajo a arriba (aunque como se repite a la inversa no importa). Entonces cambia la animación a `bottom:0` y `bottom:400px` para eso:

```css
#pelota {
  position: absolute;
  animation: rebota 1s alternate infinite ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rebota {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png" width="100" height="100" id="pelota">
```

Si lo que quieres es usar `top`, lo que puedes hacer es usar unas unidades diferentes. En lugar de definir las alturas con `px`, podrías usar  `vh` (que tiene en cuenta la altura de la pantalla). Pero eso haría que necesitases `calc` para corregir el valor de la altura de la pelota (nada complejo realmente).

```css
#pelota {
  position: absolute;
  animation: rebota 1s alternate infinite ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rebota {
  0% {
    top: 600px; /* dejamos el valor original como fallback para mayor soporte */
    top: calc(100vh - 70px);
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px; /* dejamos el valor original como fallback para mayor soporte */
    top: calc(100vh - 500px);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tenvinilo.com/vinilos-decorativos/img/preview/vinilo-infantil-pelota-futbol-color-1399.png" width="100" height="100" id="pelota">
```